# Can you take Bowwow out after returning him to MeowMeow?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening, zelda-links-awakening-2019

Hes super useful because he finds seashells for you, but after you bring it back, you seemingly can't bring him back with you for a walk. He's stuck chained to his post.

So is there a way to take this good metal boi on a seashell finding walk after you complete the quest where he's kidnapped?

Comment: I think this means you get locked out of one of the dungeons...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. However:

> If you collect 15 secret seashells and go to the Seashell Mansion, you'll be given the Seashell Sensor, an item that alerts you when a seashell is nearby. (Nintendo Switch version only.)